# Nested jQuery UI Accordions won't open with .active

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I have nested jQuery accordions in my markup where I try to auto-open on page load according to the path that was last opened in previous sessions.
I saved the path into a cookie, loading the cookie and run the following code

```
path.forEach(function(label){
    var element = root.find("[data-caption='"+label+"']");
    element.parent().accordion( "option", "active", parseInt(element.attr('data-index')) );
    root = element.children().eq(1);
});
```

The issue is that for some reason the 'active' takes effect only for the first accordion and non of the nested ones.

I checked several times and:

1. element.parent() is indeed an accordion (otherwise it would have thrown an error).
2. data-caption is a unique key for elements in each iteration.
3. element.children().eq(1) is the active panel (according to the structure of jQuery UI Accordion).
4. the active element I am asking to open indeed exists for each iteration.

I don't know what is the issue here, any ideas?

Comment: Point 3 seems unlikely, especially considering you use it with `.find`. Could you provide your accordion's HTML? Or construct a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by myself and post here for future reference.

The issue is this part of the code

```
parseInt(element.attr('data-index'))
```

And the reason lies with how accordion counts elements within its panel.
In my panel I had several html elements which were not accordion and several which were. Now the code above brought me the index of the accordion element in compare to the entire panel.
The issue is that for some reason .active only counts sub elements which are accordion themselves. So for example if the panel index of an element is 3 but it has 1 non-accordion element before it in the panel, then it's "active" index is actually 2.
I don't know why they chose for this behaviour, but there you have it.

My solution was to place a different attribute on the element with it's "active" index and use it instead of data-index.

Now everything works like a charm.